# how to test a function which is provided to children component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am running a test on jest and it says that some certain code lines are not covered. In my case it is the line where Resizable component is defined. This component comes from npm package called "re-resizable"

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state({
            height: 0
        })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <Resizable
                  onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, d) => {
                      this.setState({
                          height: this.state.height + d.height
                      })
                  )}
               />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

So seems like I have to test the onResizeStop props which provides a function to the Resizable component. How can I trigger the onResizeStop event and assert that height state was changed? I am using enzyme version 3.10.0 and jest version 26.5.3

Comment: Don't seek a 100% coverage.
I suppose Resizable comes from a third library?
You may mock the `Resizable` that will call your `onResizeStop` function.

Comment: Not looking for 100% coverage, but would be good to learn how to test custom events. Yes Resizable comes from third-party lib called re-resizable. Could you share any link how can I call the onResizeStop function?